# Joining tables and create a "LoggedIn" variable if statement matches

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join

So I got two tables. Players and Connections. Each table contains an ID. players.ID and connections.AccountID.

I want to create a query that `SELECTS` from players and returns "LoggedIn" in a temporary field if the ID exists inside the connections table.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT P.ID, 
      (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM CONNECTIONS CON 
       WHERE CON.AccountID = P.ID 
       LIMIT 1) LOGGEDIN
FROM PLAYERS P
```

In the `LOGGEDIN` column you will have `1` if user exists in `CONNECTIONS` or `0` if not. But if you will not save too much data into `CONNECTIONS` table, you could just create a persistent field in `PLAYERS` table and update this data when the user log in and log out. This structure only makes sense if the `CONNECTIONS` is your log history.